# Python: TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable and IndexError: string index out of range

Tags: python

What's the way to tokenize/separate the input passed in the function?
For example, if `12356` is passed as an input, and I want to access, let's say 3rd symbol, which is `3`, what will I do?
I have tried the below code in my function, but it's giving error:

```
print(s[2]) IndexError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Code:

```
def s_test(input):
    s=input
    print(s)
    print(s[2])

s_test(12356)
```

In one other program, when I am doing the same, I am getting an error:

```
"IndexError: string index out of range" for the instruction print(s[2])
```

Thanks

Comment: You are passing an `int`, not an `str` to your method. Either pass it as a string `"123456"`, or cast it in your method: `s = str(input)`

Comment: Thanks for answering.

In this program I am getting error:" IndexError: string index out of range," even after converting input to string. Please have a look at line 119: https://repl.it/Dfey/4

Comment: What is the *exact* value of the data you are passing to that method? Have you tried printing it out before you try to access it to in fact see you can actually access the string at that index?

Comment: Yes, when I am printing only s (print(s)) the output is correct. But, when I am printing s[2] (print(s[2])) there's an error "IndexError: string index out of range"

Comment: What is `s` though?

Comment: s is a variable in which I am storing the value of argument passed in the function. Please have a look at line no. 119: https://repl.it/Dfey/4

Comment: Following up from idjaw's comment, you cannot index a string, but you can index a list. So basically you want to convert to a string and the list the string. So if input is an integer do s = list(str(input)) and this should fix it

Comment: @jfish003 You definitely can access a string by index `print("abcdef"[3])` will output `d`

Comment: @user6867490 You are shadowing the [built-in input](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input). In the method of question, change the usage of `input` to something else. Never use the same name as built-ins. When you make the change, run your code again.

Comment: I did it, but now for print(s[0]), I am getting error "IndexError: list index out of range" 
Please have a look at line no. 120: https://repl.it/Dfey/5

Comment: I copy pasted your code and ran it and you in fact have an empty list you are dealing with. So this error is valid. Please troubleshoot carefully ensuring you are passing the right data.

Comment: I apologize, I have always done list(str(x)) so I guess I assumed you couldn't index a string but you can. idjaw seems to have discovered the source of your error then, you are not giving input

Comment: I have changed input to ipt everywhere in the code, but still for print(s[0]), I am getting error "IndexError: string index out of range"
I am getting correct output for print(s), but getting error for print(s[0]). I think, I am giving input. Please clarify.
Please have a look at line no. 120: https://repl.it/Dfey/6

Comment: @user6867490 , try like this. Hope you'll understand. 
`if len(s) > 0:
     print(s[0])
    else:
     print('you are passing an empty value for "input".')`

Comment: Thank you, so much guys. Now, I know where I was wrong. :)
Actually, I have to implement this algorithm in NDRecognize function:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0By6GDPYLwp2cdWlWbGJNLTdfZjQ

And, I was stuck in the first step itself. I will think, how to compute the rest of the algorithm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problems are into the following `function`.

```
def TestComponents(months, days, years, seps):
    print("\nTest Months FSA")
    # print(months.m[0][1])
    for input in ["", "0", "1", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13"]:
        print("'%s'\t%s" % (input, NDRecognize(input, months)))
    print("\nTest Days FSA")
    for input in ["", "0", "1", "9", "10", "11", "21", "31", "32"]:
        print("'%s'\t%s" % (input, NDRecognize(input, days)))
    print("\nTest Years FSA")
    for input in ["", "1899", "1900", "1901", "1999", "2000", "2001", "2099", "2100"]:
        print("'%s'\t%s" % (input, NDRecognize(input, years)))
    print("\nTest Separators FSA")
    for input in ["", ",", " ", "-", "/", "//", ":"]:
        print("'%s'\t%s" % (input, NDRecognize(input, seps)))


def TestDates(dates):
    print("\nTest Date Expressions FSA")
    for input in ["", "12 31 2000", "12/31/2000", "12-31-2000", "12:31:2000",
                  "1 2 2000", "1/2/2000", "1-2-2000", "1:2:2000",
                  "00-31-2000", "12-00-2000", "12-31-0000",
                  "12-32-1987", "13-31-1987", "12-31-2150"]:
        print("'%s'\t%s" % (input, NDRecognize(input, dates)))
```

You are executing a `for` loop over this type of list `["", "0", "1", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13"]` which contain `1` empty string in the `first` element. So in the first iteration an empty value is passed to the `NDRecognize(input, dates))` function into every `for` loop. That's why an error occurred into the `NDRecognize(input, dates))` function.

I hope you understand what I'm telling. Thank you.